# sp_MSforeachtable to execute procedure on each table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to print some dynamic query to execute a procedure on all tables in the database. This is what I've written so far -

```sql
EXEC SP_MSFOREACHTABLE '
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
       WHERE COLUMN_NAME="EMAIL_S" AND TABLE_NAME=PARSENAME("?",1))
    BEGIN
        PRINT ''EXEC DROPCONSTANT @TBLNAME=''+PARSENAME("?",1)
                  +'', @FLDNAME=''''EMAIL_S'''' ''
        PRINT CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)
    END
'
```

The output is not what I expect it to be -

```sql
EXEC DROPCONSTANT @TBLNAME=bill, @FLDNAME='EMAIL_S'
```

But what I really want it -

```sql
EXEC DROPCONSTANT @TBLNAME='bill', @FLDNAME='EMAIL_S'
```

Comment: Looks like @Aaron's answer covers this fairly well, but if you do need `sp_MSForeachtable` in the future, it has a [parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9680217/15498) that lets you filter the tables it actually executes against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a bunch of `'`.

```
PRINT ''DROPCONSTANT @TBLNAME=''''''+PARSENAME("?",1)+'''''', @FLDNAME=''''EMAIL_S'''' ''
```

Comment: This works fine. Just couldn't figure out that we need 6 quotes.

Answer (score 7):

How about this instead:

```
DECLARE @output NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @output += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
  + 'EXEC DROPCONSTANT @TBLNAME=''' + t.name + ''','
  + '@FLDNAME=''EMAIL_S'';'
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
  ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
  WHERE c.name = 'EMAIL_S';

SELECT @output;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @output;
```