# SQL Query to delete data from tables defined in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav-2009

I'm trying to delete data from a number of tables in my SQL base.

In the database I have a table called company which contains the names of each table that I need to delete data from.

lets assume that I have 3 companies in my company table.

What I want to do is delete all records in some certain tables in each company.

So, in the company table I have the following 3 records:

```
1  2  3
```

There are also the following tables in the database which depicts each company's scanned documents.

```
dbo.1.documents
dbo.2.documents
dbo.3.documents
```

What I am trying to do is to create a SQL query that will run through the dbo.company table and clear the document tables based on the company names found there.

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @MyField varchar;
BEGIN
SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
select top 1000 [Name] from dbo.Company    

OPEN @MyCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
INTO @MyField

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  delete * from 'dbo.'+@MyField+'$documents'

  FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
  INTO @MyField 
END; 

CLOSE @MyCursor ;
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```

I am not sure how the syntax should go but I imagine it is something like this.

Anybody care to chip in on how I can dynamically delete the data based on the records in the dbo.company.name?

Comment: Can you use php for this task?

Comment: No. Im afraid it must solely be an sql query

Comment: Is this NAV? You may get additional help if you tag with the dynamics product you are using.

Comment: This looks like SQL Server. Please tag that. You'll need to use Dynamic SQL for this task. Although this `$documents` is throwing me off.

Comment: Remove delete statement and add EXEC('DELETE from dbo.'+@MyField+'.documents')

Comment: Maybe look at FOREACHTABLE See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9942196/1662973

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use dynamic sql.

Replace the delete-statement with code below (the declare can be done at the start):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @sql = N'delete from dbo.'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@MyField)+'documents'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: This solved my problem completely. I had to add a length to the varchar variable in your convert but apart from that it was flawless.

Comment: The performance on delete is somewhat lacking so i changed it to use truncate table (there is a lot of data in these tables) But again. Thanks - Worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage dynamic sql a little differently and avoid all the hassle and overhead of creating a cursor for this. I am using the values in your table to generate a number of delete statements and then executing them. This is a lot less effort to code and eliminates that nasty cursor.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'delete dbo.[' + c.Name + '$documents];'
from dbo.Company

select @SQL --uncomment the line below when you are satisfied the dynamic sql is correct
--exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Passing the satisfactory dynamic query to `sp_executesql` will be more productive. `@SQL` didn't make it to the last line.