# Is it posible to use sp_MSforeachtable procedure to Create Trigger on all tables in a database

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

Am trying to Create a function that would loop through all the tables in a database and Create a trigger if it does not exist.After  some research i came across the store procedure:"sp_MSforeachtable procedure" Can some one help me with a code that would use the function to create the trigger below.The Trigger works fine just that now i need to make sure it is applied on all table using a loop.NB I don't want to manual run it on all table.Performance wise i know  may not be the best idea to have triggers on all tables in a database. here is my trigger

```
USE [Issue]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Update_DateCreated_DateModified]
ON  [dbo].[Patient] 
FOR  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @getDateCreated Datetime = GETDATE()
DECLARE @getDateModified DATETIME=GETDATE()
DECLARE @patient_nin VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT NIN FROM INSERTED i)
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE dbo.Patient SET DateCreated=@getDateCreated,DateModified=@getDateModified
END   
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is NOT tested, but it should be something like this.

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''?_Update_DateCreated_DateModified''))
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = 
N''CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[?_Update_DateCreated_DateModified]
ON  ?
FOR  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @getDateCreated Datetime = GETDATE()
DECLARE @getDateModified DATETIME=GETDATE()
DECLARE @patient_nin VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT NIN FROM INSERTED i)
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE ? SET DateCreated=@getDateCreated,DateModified=@getDateModified
END   
;'''
```

The ? is replaced with the table name. If I remember correctly

Comment: I Got this error:Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Comment: ,since the code is looping through all the tables.It means the ? cannot be static variable.Is this right?

Comment: another error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Update_DateCreated_DateModified, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

Comment: @kombo ? is replaced with schema.table. You can use it like it is used here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679997/sql-server-sp-msforeachtable-usage-to-select-only-those-tables-which-meet-some-c). Try replacing GO with ;

Comment: @kombo BTW becarefull this is excecuted for ALL tables, not just those in dbo schema.

Comment: thanks @NLwino. i appreciate your help.Command(s) completed successfully.

Comment: i create two tables on the database now but it creates the trigger on one table and then display the error:Msg 2714, Level 16, State 2, Procedure Update_DateCreated_DateModified, Line 10
There is already an object named 'Update_DateCreated_DateModified' in the database.

Comment: @kombo Edited which should solve the problem. Triggernames are now: TableName_Update_DateCreated_DateModified. This will create new triggers for all tables, so delete your old ones that do the same job.