# SQL Server query - copy all tables from query into database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have question about copy tables from a query into other database.

I use this query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLENAME = '2000'
```

This query returns tables. And I would like to copy all the returned tables into my other database.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you want to create the same table schema in to other DB or you want to copy data??

Comment: I want to filter specific tables from one database and copy the specific tables from the query in my new database

Comment: You can create linked server 


 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx                        Then you can copy the table using , server.database.schema.table            **select  *
into    DbName.dbo.NewTable
from    LinkedServer.DbName.dbo.OldTable**  This will create new table with same schema and structure .

Comment: Or you can access linked server using double dots also  **SELECT * FROM xxxxxDB..xxxTable** and you can easily copy your data in to new database.

Comment: Yes but there are over 600 tables.. when i use the query:

select * into DbName.dbo.NewTable from LinkedServer.DbName.dbo.OldTable

i must named each NewTable and each OldTable..

Answer (score 0):

have a look at `sp_MSforeachtable` and feed your table names into it from `information_schema.tables`

there is a good example here to get you started [sp_MSforeachtable example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrissk/archive/2010/06/27/example-code-executing-tsql-for-each-table-in-a-database.aspx)

Another example that can be modified is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679997/sql-server-sp-msforeachtable-usage-to-select-only-those-tables-which-meet-some-c)

This could be amended to suit your needs:

```
Exec sp_MSforeachtable
@command1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS [?] FROM ?",
@whereand = "and uid = (SELECT schema_id FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'dbo') 
 and o.name LIKE 'IIN%'"
```

Replace @command1 with your copy code (something like `SELECT * INTO ...` and replace @whereand with your filter for your tables or an `IN` statement if you have a list.