# Update a column present in multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

How to update a column which is present in multiple tables?

I am designing a DW having multiple Dim_tables with common column named DS how to set its value to 1 ?

i tried this but it gives error

```
use [DW]
go
exec sp_msforeachtable 'UPDATE ? SET [DS]=1'
go
```

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'DS'.

Comment: What did you do to find the problem? What does the message tell you?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679997/sql-server-sp-msforeachtable-usage-to-select-only-those-tables-which-meet-some-c

Comment: @usr: its throwing same error evry time i try like _invalid column name_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i got it !
the error is because the code is compiled before you check for the column. I could do like this instead :

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 
@command1='
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=PARSENAME("?",2) AND TABLE_NAME=PARSENAME("?",1) AND COLUMN_NAME="DS")
BEGIN
   EXEC(''
          BEGIN
              UPDATE ? SET [DS]=1
          END
        '')
END
'
```