# SQL query searching a common field in all tables

Tags: sql

All tables in a DB have the fields creationdate and revisiondate, which are date fields just as you'd think.  Looking for a SQL query to find all instances where creationdate > '2017-02-01'.  I'm not able to find an example where you loop through each table to return all new records as of X date in a DB.  The DB has 1000 tables so I need to be able to search dynamically.  The one table version of the query is (select * from tableA where creationdate > '2017-02-01')  I just need to do that against all tables.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679997/sql-server-sp-msforeachtable-usage-to-select-only-those-tables-which-meet-some-c

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT schema.column_1, schema.column2
FROM   table_name_1
UNION
SELECT schema.column_same_datatype, schema.column2_same_datatype
FROM   table_name_2
WHERE  creation_date > '2017-02-01';
```

NOTE: YOu should have precaution about date format. I think the most common date format is DD-MM-YYYY.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I'm looking to query on the field creationdate across all tables in the DB vs. just a single or two tables of known name.  My DB has 1000 tables, each has creationdate and revisiondate on each record.